# Themes of Semantic-UI CSS Framework

Tags: css, button, semantic-ui

I am trying to get the css files for Semantic-UI buttons (Amazon Theme). I tried to follow their instructions on how to build themes which is way beyond my skill level and got me lost. I will really appreciate any sort of help to get these buttons (Amazon Theme) css file. 
1- Is there a simple way ?
2- Are they ready available with the desired theme?
http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html

Answer (score 0):

2-- Precompiled non-default (packaged) themed components are neither available on [Semantic UI's official site](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html) nor in the [dist folder on their github repo](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/dist).

However you can cheat your way to the precompiled Amazon buttons, because they are available as resources on the [Theming Demo site](http://semantic-org.github.io/example-github/). 
Open this site, which looks like github, except that it has a paint bucket icon next to the notification icon in the top right. Click this paint bucket icon, and a theming sidebar will appear on the left. You'll have to select your desired theme for the resources to load, but then you can grab them via the browser's Developer Tools Sources or Network tab.

1-- If you'd like to give another chance to the build process, here's how:

Prerequisites: Install [NodeJs with Npm](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) (run `npm i -g gulp` in command line).

1. [Download](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI) (and unpack) the Semantic UI sources
2. Navigate to the folder you extracted or downloaded the Semantic-UI sources, and do the followings in command line:
3. Run `npm install`.

   1. When asked, choose Automatic (for installation)
   2. and then choose Yes (for removing setup files)
   3. and then No (for building Semantic now)
4. Edit the `./src/theme.config` file, and change `@button: 'default';` to `@button: 'amazon';`
5. Run `gulp build`

After the build is done, you should find the compiled css files in the `./dist` folder, and your custom Amazon `button.css` in the `./dist/components` folder.